# csvファイルから特定の文字列のみを抽出したい

Tags: python, python3

以下のCSVを読み込み、ツイート内容を出力する際、特定の文字列リツイートのアカウント（RT ＠＊＊＊）を含むアカウントのみを抽出し、別の列(test4)に反映させたいです。

実行環境として、Windows にPythonをインストールしています。

■CSVの内容

```
test1,tets2,test3,test4
RT @senti:学んでみたい言語は？
```

実装したい内容

```
test1,　　　　　　　　　　　     test4
RT @senti:学んでみたい言語は？　 @senti　
casaseis
RT @sancho:今日は？　　　　　　　@sancho
ocho
RT @sacamuchi:楽しい          @sacamuchi
```

ウェブサイトで調べながら下記のコードを参照しましたが上手くcsvの行(test1)からRTアカウントを取得できないです。

RTのアカウントをのみ抽出するにはどのように設定すれば良いでしょうか。
お手数ですが、教えていただけますでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 12000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 12000)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 12000)

df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/catuti/Desktop/tweets_2019.csv', encoding='cp932', names=["test1", "RT @"], usecols=[0, 1], skiprows=[0], skipfooter=0, engine='python')
df= df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
df= df.replace({'\r': ''}, regex=True)
df = df.query('test1.str.contains("RT @") or 内容.str.contains("RT @")')
df.to_html(r'C:/Users/catuti/Desktop/tweets_20191.csv',escape=False)
```

Comment: やろうとしている事自体はなんとなく分かるのですが、現状で「うまくいかない」はどのような結果になるのでしょうか？また、元のCSVに対して(意図する)出力結果とが合っていないように見えます。"casaseis" や "ocho" はどのようにCSVに含まれているのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。casaseisとochoはRT＠のアカウントが含まない時です。結果としてはエラーになりアカウント取得できないです。

Answer (score 1):

ユーザ名に対する正規表現を利用します。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650007/regular-expression-for-twitter-username

```py
# 読み込み済みのdfは存在すると仮定
import re

regex = re.compile(r"^RT (@(\w){1,15})")

def get_username(text):
    try:
        return regex.match(text).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        return None

df["test4"] = [get_username(x) for x in df["test1"]]
df.to_csv("test_out.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: 上記の方法でできませんでした。新規で質問しました。お手隙の際にご確認おねがします。

Comment: 新規質問件名：文字列からアカウントだけを取得する

Comment: 私が試した限り、この方法でできましたよ。できなかったなら発生したエラー等を書いてほしいですね。できなかった可能性としては、要件と正規表現が一致していないか、pythonバージョンが異なるためです。"RT @*"という要件が正規表現と一致しているかご自身で確認されたら良いのでは。

Comment: finditerでも動作しましたが、簡潔にするためにmatchを使うように変更しました。